# Migrate from NavHost to AnimatedNavHost

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, uinavigationcontroller, android-jetpack-compose

Hi I'm trying to migrate my Android Studio project from `NavHost` to `AnimatedNavHost`, so I have made this changing:

- Replace rememberNavController() with rememberAnimatedNavController()
- Replace NavHost with AnimatedNavHost
  Finded on this blog: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/animations-in-navigation-compose-36d48870776b

And I don't add any animation, but when I try to run my app the compiler say to me this error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method rememberNavController(Landroidx/compose/runtime/Composer;I)Landroidx/navigation/NavHostController; in class Landroidx/navigation/compose/NavHostControllerKt; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostControllerKt' appears in /data/app/~~3ss2A6J7mK0SYONGyPJOUw==/com.example.soschool-o-E9YEHWVSYOUf5K7L3c5Q==/base.apk!classes11.dex)

Now I'll attach the two classes interested:
**NavigationGraph:**

```
@ExperimentalAnimationApi
@ExperimentalPagerApi
@Composable
fun SetupNavGraph(
    navController: NavHostController,
    startDestination: String
) {
    AnimatedNavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = startDestination
    ) {
        composable(route = Screen.Welcome.route) {
            WelcomeScreen(navController = navController)
        }
        composable(route = Screen.Home.route) {
            HomeScreen()
        }
        composable(route = Screen.Login.route){
            LoginScreen()
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
@ExperimentalAnimationApi
@ExperimentalPagerApi
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var splashViewModel: SplashViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        installSplashScreen().setKeepOnScreenCondition {
            !splashViewModel.isLoading.value
        }

        setContent {
            SOSchoolTheme {
                val screen by splashViewModel.startDestination
                val navController = rememberAnimatedNavController()
                SetupNavGraph(navController = navController, startDestination = screen)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the app without `Animated` stuff everything is fine, but when I change `AnimatedNavController()` to `rememberAnimatedNavController()` on `MainActivity` and `NavHost` to    `AnimatedNavHost` the app crash and say the error that i wrote up.

Comment: What about `Replace import androidx.navigation.compose.navigation with import com.google.accompanist.navigation.animation.navigation1?`

Comment: where? I can't find this import

Comment: The blog you mentioned describes two more replaces (I mentioned only one). I just wonder if you have done those or not

Comment: yes, I'have changed all that stuff, but I still have the error

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Changing version to 0.21.1-beta worked for me.

implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-navigation-animation:0.21.1-beta"

Answer (score 1):

Replace the import from `import androidx.navigation.compose.composable` to `import com.google.accompanist.navigation.animation.composable`. It was one of the issues listed on accompanist github.

Answer (score 0):

set `compileSdkVersion` to 33 or latest one whichever is higher with all required changes like correct import and youre reading integrate animation in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to 0.28.0 worked for me :

```
implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-navigation-animation:0.28.0"
```

Then following this sample app for the animations:

https://github.com/google/accompanist/blob/main/sample/src/main/java/com/google/accompanist/sample/navigation/animation/AnimatedNavHostSample.kt